# Utility to monitor command output changes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, watch

Please, suggest native (from standard repositories) Ubuntu utility, similar to [topless](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/sysutils/topless.html) from ports in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used topless, but I often use `watch` on Linux.

Here's a [good article](http://beerpla.net/2007/08/04/watch-a-useful-linux-command-you-may-have-never-heard-of/) on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, Kamil, this is it. Sorry, can't vote up your answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

[MultiTail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) can watch the output of programs and scripts as well as follow files (like `tail -f`).